# How to increment the interval date on Mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to increment the date value on mysql? say I have this:

```
+------+---------------------+
| PID  | mydate              |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2016-08-06 08:00:00 |
|    2 | 2016-08-06 08:00:00 |
|    3 | 2016-08-06 08:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

And I wanted to make each value incremented by 10 hours, something like this:

```
+------+---------------------+
| PID  | mydate              |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2016-08-06 18:00:00 |
|    2 | 2016-08-07 04:00:00 |
|    3 | 2016-08-07 14:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

I have tried this

```
update mytable set mydate = now() + interval 10 hour;
```

but that will update every value to 10 hours from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables for this:

```
update mytable cross join
       (select @i := 0) params
    set mydate = mydate + interval 10 * (@i := @i + 1) hour;
```

EDIT:

I notice there *is* an ordering in the original data.  For that to work:

```
set @i = 0;

update mytable 
    set mydate = mydate + interval 10 * (@i := @i + 1) hour
    order by id;
```

Or even:

```
update mytable 
    set mydate = mydate + interval 10 * (id - 1) hour
    order by id;
```

This only works if `id` increments by 1 and has no gaps.

Comment: it works, but the first value incremented by 20hour, but it works, thanks :)

Comment: Nice example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3caf05/1).  I'm curious how the order is enforced.

Comment: @sgeddes . . . Funny, it didn't even occur to me (before) that the intention was to order things by the `pid`.  It is really obvious on second look.  Good catch.