# How to use order by in update syntax on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to use `order by` in this query:

```
update mytable cross join
       (select @i := 0) params
    set mydate = mydate + interval 10 * (@i := @i + 1) hour;
```

My reference is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799803/how-to-increment-the-interval-date-on-mysql), as in that question let say I want to order the PID descending,

```
update mytable cross join
           (select @i := 0) params
        set mydate = mydate + interval 10 * (@i := @i + 1) hour order by PID desc;
```

But with that query I got `ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY`

The original query is working fine but I can't use `order by` in it.

Comment: You cannot use this way.

Comment: Then how to do it?

Comment: ORDER BY makes zero sense in an UPDATE. ORDER BY only has relevance in a SELECT. What purpose do you think an ORDER BY in an UPDATE would serve?

Comment: Have you see the link? it updates the date according to PID 1,2,3 and I want to update it 3,2,1, is that wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like below might do:

```
UPDATE mytable MT 
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT 
 *,
 @i := @i + 1 AS paramNumber
 FROM 
 mytable 
 cross join(select @i := 0) params
 ORDER BY PID DESC
) AS t
ON MT.PID = t.PID
SET MT.mydate = MT.mydate + INTERVAL (10 * (t.paramNumber)) HOUR
```

> <kbd>[14.2.11 UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)</kbd>
>
> **Single-table syntax:**
>
> ```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
>     SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
>     [WHERE where_condition]
>     [ORDER BY ...]
>     [LIMIT row_count]
> ```
>
> **Multiple-table syntax:**
>
> ```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
>     SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
>     [WHERE where_condition]
> ```
>
> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is
>   updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For
>   multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL doesn't allow to use `ORDER BY` in an UPDATE statement with a JOIN. But you can avoid the JOIN by splitting your statement in two:

```sql
set @i := 0;
update mytable 
set mydate = mydate + interval 10 * (@i := @i + 1) hour 
order by PID desc;
```

A tricky way to keep it in one statement without a JOIN is to initialize `@i` in the ORDER BY clause:

```sql
update mytable 
set mydate = mydate + interval 10 * (@i := @i + 1) hour
order by PID desc, @i := 0;
```